# IE8 Google Visualization Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

I have a Google charts solution working in most browsers except IE8. When I move the mouse over the chart I get a `permission denied` error from a Google visualization API script (line 83, char 16).

The script in question is this one: http://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/c3581c99759b4a64cb69ca21ab634266/format+en_GB,default+en_GB,ui+en_GB,corechart+en_GB.I.js

Here is a screenshot of the IE8 error: http://screencast.com/t/Ccyqfmuv

Just to be clear, the chart renders correctly and the error only seems to occur when the chart is hovered over.

I have tested in IE9/10 and all is fine. I have also tested in http://www.browserstack.com/ in case there was some odd local multiple IE thing going on.

Any suggestions on what it might be?

Comment: Post javascript code reproduces the problem and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

see if the following fix works:

```
function drawChart() {
   var __instance__ = arguments.callee;
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<your data here>);
   var chartCnt = document.getElementById('chart-container');

   !__instance__.testChart &&
       (__instance__.testChart = new google.visualization.BarChart(chartCnt));

    __instance__.testChart.clearChart();
    __instance__.testChart.draw(data, { width:600, height:400 });
 }
```

ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/QoCPFv1tKkQ

Comment: Or you could simply call .clearChart() when you discard a chart instance from the DOM.. worked for me.